# HTML Drag and Drop and Struts

Tags: html, jsp, drag-and-drop, struts

I've been trying to implement the new "Drag and Drop" file and upload feature, using the code from SitePoint.com. I am using Struts Framework as well. FormFile made my uploads easier, I could just hit on "choose" and click away. But, I just can't seem to get it to work the DnD with Struts. The ActionForm validates and reports that the file size is 0! Here's the code from SitePoint.com (js):

```
(function() {

// getElementById
function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


// output information
function Output(msg) {
    var m = $id("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
}


// file drag hover
function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
}


// file selection
function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
        UploadFile(f);
    }

}


// output file information
function ParseFile(file) {

    Output(
        "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
        "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
        "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
        "</strong> bytes</p>"
    );

    // display an image
    if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong><br />" +
                '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" /></p>'
            );
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    // display text
    if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong></p><pre>" +
                e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") +
                "</pre>"
            );
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
            else{
                var reader=new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}


// upload JPEG files
function UploadFile(file) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {

        // create progress bar
        var o = $id("progress");
        var progress = o.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
        progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("upload " + file.name));


        // progress bar
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
        }, false);

        // file received/failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
            }
        };

        // start upload
        xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
        xhr.send(file);

    }

}


// initialize
function Init() {

    var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
        filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
        submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

    // file select
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

    // is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {

        // file drop
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
        filedrag.style.display = "block";

            }

}

// call initialization file
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
}


})();
```

---

The jsp (just messing around):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Upload File</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
</head>
<body>
<form id="upload" action="../Repositore/upload_file.do" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>File Upload Form</legend>
    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000" />
    <div>
        <label for="fileselect">File to upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="file" multiple="multiple" />
        <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table border='0' cellpadding='2'>
            <tr><td><label for="ftags">Tags:</label></td><td> <input type='text' id="ftags" name='tags'/></td><td>(Separate by commas)</td></tr> 
            <tr><td><label for="desc">Description:</label></td><td> <textarea name="description" id="desc" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="comment">Yes</input></td></tr>
    </div>
    <div id="submitbutton">
        <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="progress"></div>
<div id="messages">
    <p>Status:</p>
</div>    
<script src="js/filedrag.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

What could be wrong? Help?

Comment: Before use the new plugin's just check file upload working in a normal way. If it works try that out.

Comment: It works fine without the drag and drop feature.

Comment: From understand your script `xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);` line says upload the file directly once you have dragged into it. And you are doing it asynchronously. A few details required from you, When you got file size 0? when going with ajax or submitting the form. And as I checked [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com) it having some browser constraints. Which browser version you are using? Make sure it supports your work.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome 40. The filesize returned 0 in the ActionForm, while validating (to see if the upload is null). I was using FormFile (Struts), and I'm kind of starting to think that it is what's been messing around with the whole drag and drop, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you getting my point? plugin trying to upload the file once you were dropped in, since it was ajax coded. Check your browser console once you dropped the file in. Post the error from console if you have it.